# How to quantify the period-to-period variability of EVI index time series?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, evi

How to quantify the period-to-period variability of EVI  index time series
(Qi), Qi for each two periods is formulated simply as:
Qi= Vm+1,i- Vmi;
Where Qi, Vm+1,i, and Vm, are the VIs variation, and the values of the i-th pixel VIs for period m and m+1, respectively.

```
// Apply EVI calculation to each image in the collection
var eviCollection = collection.map(calculateEVI)
                    .select('EVI');

// Sort the collection by date in descending order
var sortedCollection = eviCollection.sort('system:time_start', false);
print(' Sorted collection', sortedCollection);

// Compute the variation between consecutive images
var eviVariation = sortedCollection.map(function(image, index) {
  if (index < sortedCollection.size().subtract(1)) {
    var nextImage = sortedCollection.toList(sortedCollection.size()).get(index + 1);
    var variation = image.select('EVI').subtract(ee.Image(nextImage).select('EVI'));
    return variation.rename('EVI_variation')
      .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
  } else {
    return image.rename('EVI_variation');
  }
});
```